# How to create an array in mongoose Schema and how to send data to it through json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I am creating an E-commerce project and I am in a dilemma creating an Orders Schema. According to me, I am convinced that a customer cannot sometimes order one item and therefore the orders should be in an array, but I am having trouble navigating through this as I am a beginner. this is what I have come up with within my model and controller but whenever I post data the res.json that I receive comes with an empty object.

I hope someone can help with this.

My Order model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const ordersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true,
        ref:"users",
    },
    orders:[
        {
            item:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required:true,
                ref:'products'
        
            },
            quatity:{
                type:Number,
                required:true,
                default:1
        
            },
            price:{
                type:Number,
                required:true,
        
            }

        }

    ]   
});

export const ordersModel = mongoose.model("orders", ordersSchema);
```

My controller code for creating an order

```
import { ordersModel} from "../models/orders.model.js"
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'


export const makeOrder =asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    const {item, price, quantity, payment} = req.body;
    
    if(!item || !price ){
        res.sendStatus(401)
        res.json({message: 'There is no order to make'});
    }else{
          
          const order = new ordersModel(
            {
                user:req.user._id,
                order:[
                    {
                        item,
                        price,
                        quantity,
                        payment
                    }
                ],
            }
          );

          const made_order = await (order.save());

          if(made_order){
              return res.json({
                orderId:made_order._id,
                customer:made_order.user._id,
                order:{
                        item:made_order.item,
                        price:made_order.price,
                        quantity:made_order.quantity,
                        payment:made_order.payment,
                    }
                
              })
          }
    }
    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a typo when creating a new order. You have `orders` field in schema but you are passing `order` without `s` at the end when creating a new order. Below is the correct implementation

```
const order = new ordersModel(
  {
      user: req.user._id,
      orders: [
          {
              item,
              price,
              quantity,
              payment
          }
      ],
  }
);
```

You also don't have `payment` field in schema but you are passing it when creating order. So your schema should be this if you want to include payment field

```
const ordersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true,
        ref:"users",
    },
    orders:[
        {
            item:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required:true,
                ref:'products'
        
            },
            quatity:{
                type:Number,
                required:true,
                default:1
        
            },
            price:{
                type:Number,
                required:true,
            },
            payment:{
                type:Number,
                required:true,
            }

        }

    ]   
});
```

In the end you can remove the if statement and just send a res like this

```
const made_order = await order.save();

return res.json({
      orderId:made_order._id,
      customer:made_order.user,
      orders: made_order.orders
    })
```

If you want to create multiple orders in a single call, your `makeOrder` controller should be like this

```
export const makeOrder = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    
    if(!Array.isArray(req.body) || !req.body.length) {
        res.sendStatus(401)
        res.json({message: 'There is no order to make'});
    } else {
      const order = new ordersModel(
        {
            user: req.user._id,
            orders: req.body,
        }
      );

      const made_order = await order.save();

      return res.json({
            orderId: made_order._id,
            customer: made_order.user,
            orders: made_order.orders
          })
     }
});
```

Then you can make an API call and send multiple orders as req body

```
 [ 
   { 
     "item":"61f58bb0d70ae52c6e470fb7", 
     "price":4500, 
     "quantity":2,
     "payment": 9000
   }, 
   { 
     "item":"61f58bb0d70ae52c6e470fb7", 
     "price":4500, 
     "quantity":2,
     "payment": 9000
   } 
 ]
```

Comment: Okay, can write an example of JSON data that I Will send as test when testing my endpoint

Comment: You want an example of the data you will receive when you call this endpoint?

Comment: no, how you will write data in json as body when testing this endpoint I have tried something like this [
    {
            "item":"61f58bb0d70ae52c6e470fb7",
            "price":4500,
            "quntity":2
    },
    {
            "item":"61f58bb0d70ae52c6e470fb7",
            "price":4500,
            "quntity":2
    }
]  but got an error. mutliple orders

Comment: but your code is good i am no longer receiving the empty object

Comment: Since you are destructuring all the order fields from req.body, you need to send data in a single object containing all fields like this - { item: "61f58bb0d70ae52c6e470fb7", price: 4500, quantity: 2, payment: 9000 }

Comment: its not possible

Comment: What's not possible?

Comment: the JSON format you've just shown me

Comment: I am tryna find a way of making more than one order using JSON

Comment: Then you will have to change the logic inside makeOrder controller to create multiple orders instead of one which is the case right now.

Comment: i belive the cart will have more than one item or is it note the same case

Comment: I have updated my answer to add case for handling multiple orders. Please try using the new `makeOrder` controller